# Is the HTML 5 audio element broken in all browsers except Firefox?

Tags: node.js, html5-audio

Using Google Chrome (V72.0.3626.119) I am finding that the `<audio>` element just doesn't work as expected.

I have a simple Node.js server:

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/ogg')
  res.end(fs.readFileSync('./test.ogg', {encoding: null}))
}).listen(9000)
```

I find that, using Chrome, if I navigate to `localhost:9000` then the audio starts playing automatically. But seeking is completely broken.

If I go to `localhost:9000` in Firefox then the audio shows/behaves as expected.

If I go to `localhost:9000` in safari the audio just downloads (UGH)

If I go to `localhost:9000` in Opera the audio behaves the same way as in Chrome

Am I doing anything wrong in the Node.js server?

I have found that managing the stream from server to client works (except using Safari), using this code: https://github.com/daspinola/video-stream-sample/blob/master/server.js

A related question that I asked earlier is here: [How to send an audio file to Chrome using a Node.js http server endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905334/how-to-send-an-audio-file-to-chrome-using-a-node-js-http-server-endpoint)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use `res.sendFile('./test.ogg')` instead of `res.end(fs.readFileSync('./test.ogg'))`.
Then in your HTML client just do `<audio src="/" type="audio/ogg"/>`

Comment: The audio element specifies a source that is not the same as where the page is loaded from. Also, `res.sendFile` is not Node.js - it is a method provided by express.js.